# How does different pH affect copper electroplating

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I'm currently investigating the effect on the concentration of hydrogen ions in the copper sulfate solution on the amount of copper deposited on the cathode within a certain amount of time.

I've been trying to find an answer online but have had no luck in getting a clear cut answer. I was wondering if there is anyone here willing to provide me with some insight or a suggestion for the method to carry out this experiment.

Comment: If your solution is too acidic, then hydrogen starts reducing instead of copper. If your solution is not acidic enough, your copper will hydrolyze and fall out of the solution. It is as simple as that.

Comment: Is there a more in-depth explanation as to why that happens?

Comment: Not really. Why? Chemistry has no depth. If you dig deeper, you'll find yourself in physics.

Comment: No cause it's for a lab report and I kinda need some more explanation for it.

Comment: Then write both reactions (those of electrolysis and hydrolysis) and call it a day.